# How can I make a rewrite-condition dependent on the result of a servlet/jsp?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-jk, wurfl

We have Apache on top of JBoss serving either web or mobile app.
We are currently using Apache mod-rewrite to decide where to forward the user to web or mobile (and mod-jk to mount to JBoss), based on regular expressions matching of user-agent, but that is imprecise and error prone.

We want to use a servlet or jsp on JBoss as part of deciding whether to serve the web or mobile app (the servlet checks the user-agent in WURFL to see if this is a mobile device or a web browser).

How can I make a rewrite-condition dependent on the result of a servlet/jsp ?

(I already thought about redirecting the jsp back to two possible URLs and continue the rewrite-rule logic from there, but this gets complicated with passing URL parameters back and forth)

Answer (score 1):

One conceptually simple way is to use a program-type rewritemap to  call your EE-based service to check a U-A, assuming the program couldn't just perform the check itself (if you've only got some canned java interface into that DB)

Comment: you mean like here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap
under "external rewriting program"?